# pretty url for query parametr

Tags: wp-query, filters, url-rewriting, urls, query-string

I want this link: site.com/c/web/theme/?filter_cms=wp

Convert to: site.com/c/web/theme/wp/

I found this code and edited it a bit:

```
add_action('init', function () {
     add_rewrite_rule('^c/web/theme/([a-z]+)/?$', 'index.php?product_cat=theme&filter_cms=$matches[1]', 'top');
});
```

it displays the desired category(theme) perfectly, but it does not display our filter query: ?filter_cms=wp! What is the problem?

c = WooCommerce category prefix

web = WC category

theme = WC sub-category

cms=wp = WooCommerce attribute

Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements and the code snippet you provided, it seems like you're trying to create a custom rewrite rule in WordPress that redirects a URL with query parameters to a more SEO-friendly structure. Your initial approach is on the right track. However, there might be some tweaks needed to ensure it works correctly.

The add_rewrite_rule function is used to create a new URL pattern that WordPress recognizes. In your case, you want to convert site.com/c/web/theme/?filter_cms=wp to site.com/c/web/theme/wp/.

Here's a revised version of your code:

```
add_action('init', function () {
    add_rewrite_rule('^c/web/theme/([a-z]+)/?$', 'index.php?category_name=theme&filter_cms=$matches[1]', 'top');
});

add_filter('query_vars', function ($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'filter_cms';
    return $vars;
});
```

or, this one supposidly worked.

```
add_action('init', function () {
    add_rewrite_rule('^c/web/theme/([a-z]+)/?$', 'index.php?product_cat=theme&filter_cms=$matches[1]', 'top');
});

add_filter('query_vars', function ($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'filter_cms';
    return $vars;
});
```

**Rewrite Rule:** The regular expression ^c/web/theme/([a-z]+)/?$ will match URLs of the format site.com/c/web/theme/wp/. The ([a-z]+) captures the CMS part (like 'wp') and passes it to index.php.

**Query Variables:** The add_filter with 'query_vars' allows WordPress to recognize filter_cms as a valid query variable. This is necessary for WordPress to understand and use the filter_cms variable in the URL.

After adding this code to your theme's functions.php file or in a site-specific plugin, you must flush your rewrite rules. This can be done by visiting the Settings > Permalinks page in your WordPress admin area and clicking "Save Changes" (no need to change any settings).

This code assumes that filter_cms is a recognized query parameter in your setup that influences the query for WooCommerce products. If filter_cms isn't already handled somewhere in your code or plugins, you'll also need to add the corresponding logic to interpret this query variable and modify the product query accordingly.

### Remember to test this on a staging or development environment before applying it to a live site. Also, since the URL structure is important for SEO and user experience, ensure that this change aligns with your overall SEO strategy.

Try flushing the permalinks. That is required when making changes to urls like this.

Flushing permalinks in WordPress is a process used to reset the permalink structure. This is often necessary when you create a new custom post type or change the permalink settings to ensure that the new URLs are recognized and work correctly. Here’s how to do it:

**Access the WordPress Admin Dashboard:** Log into your WordPress site's admin area.

**Go to Permalink Settings:** In the dashboard, navigate to Settings > Permalinks. You don't need to change any settings here unless you want to modify your permalink structure.

**Save Changes:** Simply click on the "Save Changes" button at the bottom of the page. This action will flush the rewrite rules and regenerate the permalink structure for your site. You don't need to actually change any permalink settings; clicking "Save Changes" with the current settings is sufficient.

Flushing permalinks in this way often resolves issues such as 404 errors on custom post types or after changing the permalink structure. Remember to do this whenever you make significant changes to your permalink settings or after setting up new custom post types or taxonomies.

Comment: hi, so you want to tell me that my code is correct? And it doesn't need any editing?
I had done what you said before but it didn't work

Comment: I updated my answer with a possible solution for you. We are answering these questions in our free time so being polite will get you better answers...

Comment: I am grateful to you and all those who help, and I know that your help is all due to grace
But you always object to what I say
I don't mean to be rude and I apologize if you feel that way
I'm just looking for an answer and guessed the problem might be something else on my site

Comment: I tested the new code, but it doesn't work, I think the problem is from the second part of the code! Here: 'index.php?category_name=theme&filter_cms=$matches[1]'
Is something wrong?

Comment: update: I changed the second part of the code from category_name to product_cat, now it displays the desired category perfectly, but it does not display our filter query: ?filter_cms=wp! What is the problem?

Comment: Ensure filter_cms is Registered Correctly: The add_filter('query_vars', ...) part of your code is supposed to register the filter_cms variable. Make sure this code is running as expected. It might be helpful to debug by adding a log statement inside this function to ensure it's being executed.